# How change Future.delayed() duration, or circumvent having to do this

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I have list of `Dismissible` widgets that I'd like to swipe left to delete. These have a an argument `confirmDismis` which takes a `Future<bool>`. I'd like to show a `SnackBar` once you've swiped an item allowing you to undo the delete for a few seconds. For this I have this method:

```
  Future<bool> _confirmDismiss() {

    var remove = true;
    var duration = Duration(seconds: 5);

    final snackbar = SnackBar(
      duration: duration,
      content: Text('This item was deleted'),
      action: SnackBarAction(
        label: 'Undo',
        onPressed: () {
          remove = false; //how to return false immediately?
        },
      ),
    );
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackbar);

    return Future.delayed(duration,(){
      return remove;
    });
  }
```

The snackbar is shown for 5 seconds, after that it disappears and the callback is triggered.

Now I'd like to return the item as soon as you hit the undo button. Right now you have to wait for the 5 seconds to pass for it to return.

I have tried timeout and Time() and many other things but I can't seem to make it work... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

@Janneman, I don't think you need to use `Future.delayed`, that could be the reason why you now have to wait 5 secs. Just use the default SnackBar functions. Here is a quick example that shows SnackBar for 5 secs and quickly changes the text on Undo,

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String text = 'Yay! A Snackbar';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('SnackBar'),
            ),
            body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Center(
                      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                    Text(text),
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        text = 'Snackbar changed';
                        setState(() {
                        });
                        final snackBar = SnackBar(
                          duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
                          content: Text(text),
                          action: SnackBarAction(
                            label: 'Undo',
                            onPressed: () {
                              text = 'Yay! A Snackbar';
                              setState(() {});
                            },
                          ),
                        );

                        // Find the Scaffold in the widget tree and use
                        // it to show a SnackBar.
                        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                      },
                      child: Text('Show SnackBar'),
                    ),
                  ])));
            })));
  }
}
```

[image: Snackbar demo]

Hope this helps. Good luck!